# Reliability of ASP Session Timeout warning

Tags: javascript, session, asp-classic, timeout

I'm looking to warn the user when his or her session times out (I'm having weird timeout problems) and I found the following code:

```
<% 
advanceWarning = 2 
jsTimeout = (session.timeout - advanceWarning) * 60000 
%> 
<script> 
window.setTimeout("alert('Session is about to expire');",<%=jsTimeout%>); 
</script>
```

Is this reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it will catch the case where the session times out on the server, assuming no other requests used session in the mean time, and the cookie doesn't expire.

So if you call a web service method or something that uses session, the session time out will be reset and you will have to catch that separately. And if your session cookie expiry (assuming you're doing it that way) is less than your timeout, then session may be lost then too.

Comment: So you're saying that if the page does any async calls, the session for that page would be reset? Would the code then incorrectly tell the user that the session had expired based on the original session time?

Comment: PS - the cookies- is that the native Classic ASP way that things are done? Cause I'm using out-of-the-box ASP.

Comment: Fairly sure the session id is stored in a cookie by default in classic ASP. I work in ASP.NET, so I'm not certain about that.

And yes, the session timeout is a sliding window, so every request you make that uses session will reset the timeout on session.

Comment: just to confirm classic ASP does rely on cookies as the default method to propoate session Id.

Answer (score 1):

In classic ASP, the Session is managed using cookies.  You can see more documentation on that here: http://w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_session.asp.  I used to use that site a lot back in the day.  If you want more control over the user's session state, you can access the cookies directly (via `Request.Cookies` and `Response.Cookies`).  http://w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_response.asp.  This may be a better solution in some situations, depending on how much content you are trying to store and how long you want it to persist.  If you don't want the session to be refreshed as a 'sliding window', you can always set a timestamp variable in either the session or the cookies collections and gain more control over the timeout that way.  One advantage to using the cookies directly is that you can access cookies directly with javascript and can avoid the spaghetti code situation.  As I don't know your end goal, I can't say for sure if this will be helpful to you, but the javascript `window.setInterval` creates a recurring function call and could be used to do asynchronous callbacks to monitor the session state.  However, if all you want to do is throw a warning `alert()`, that is probably overkill and the existing code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The above code will not work if there are multiple windows open as you are setting the expiry time from the server and that is valid only for the instant that the request is serviced. This will result in different windows showing the alert at different times.  Checking the cookie expiry with some JavaScript periodically is a much better idea.

Comment: Actually scratch that. There is no expiry set on the session cookie it appears.
Best would be to disable sliding expiration on the session and make periodic calls to the server (AJAX) to get the expiration time and then show an alert.

Comment: @Naren did this ever work for you? I.e. disabling the sliding expiration.